# Sonarqube `analyzedBefore` count mismatch

Tags: search, sonarqube

Using SonarQube search API with `analyzedBefore` set to today's date is yielding less data than the same API call which doesn't use this field.

Without any date constraints.

```
GET /api/projects/search

paging  
pageIndex   1
pageSize    100
total       49383
```

With date of today for `analyzedBefore`

```
GET /api/projects/search?analyzedBefore=2019-08-31

paging  
pageIndex   1
pageSize    100
total       30425
```

Why this there a count difference between 2 queries ? What am I missing.

Comment: You can also [provide](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects) a datetime. When you are using that does the numbers then come closer together?

Comment: I couldn't quite get datetime to work.I tried `analyzedBefore=2019-09-13T22:15Z` but it's giving invalid date + time

Comment: The [documentation](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects) states that using the 2017-10-19T13:00:00+0200 format should work.